# Row data to be saved at each iteration of both indexes in a double loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I'm kind of new in r. A got a big frame called MegaFrame (11 000 000 rows). I want to make another dataset with the mean of data MegaFrame$value, for my different sessions and P_CODE. This gives a lot of NA, because a lot of P_CODE-session pairs don't exist in the frame. I find a (I think working) solution, but now it has been running for 12 hours and still not finished.

```
colClasses = c("integer", "factor", "integer")
col.names = c("MeanMesure", "P_CODE", "session")

MeanFrame <- data.frame( mean(MegaFrame$value[MegaFrame$session == unique(MegaFrame$session)[i] && MegaFrame$P_CODE == levels(MegaFrame$P_CODE)[i]]),
                       MegaFrame$P_CODE[i],MegaFrame$session[j])
                         colnames(MeanFrame) = col.names
                      MeanFrame<-   MeanFrame[-1,]

for(i in 1:length(unique(MegaFrame$session))){
for(j in 1:length(levels(MegaFrame$P_CODE))){
x<-mean(MegaFrame$value[MegaFrame$session == unique(MegaFrame$session)[i] && MegaFrame$P_CODE == levels(MegaFrame$P_CODE)[i]])  
df<- data.frame(x,MegaFrame$P_CODE[i],MegaFrame$session[j])
colnames(df) = col.names
MeanFrame<-rbind(MeanFrame, df)
}}
```

I know I can add a condition so that the `NA` values are not added to the dataframe. But I feel my method is too heavy (making every iteration a df, changing his name, then rbind) for what I want to do, but I don't know how to make it softer. I already had a lot of trouble  with adding rows to the dataframe.

Has anybody ideas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your problem description, I don't think there is a need for `for` loop. You can try:

```
library(tidyverse);
MeanFrame <- MegaFrame %>%
    group_by(P_code, session) %>%
    summarise(mean.value = mean(value))
```

You might have to use `mean(value, na.rm = T)` instead of `mean(value)` to deal with `NA`s.

The reason why your code is so slow is because you're growing `MeanFrame` dynamically by adding row after row. That's about as inefficient as you can go, and can and should generally be avoided. If you *must* use a `for` loop, pre-allocating an empty `data.frame` of the correct dimensions would speed things up.

On a side note: It's advised to always provide a [minimal reproducible example with sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the difference of efficiency between the two solutions is impressive, your's took 2 seconds! 
For next time I'll put  reproducible example :-)